# TFS Get latest doesn't copy files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Just started in my new job, and  i'm trying to get files from tfs, but when i click 'get latest'  the popup says that all files are up to date, but there are no files under the mapped folder. The local path changes in source control window, but all the files say 'not downloaded'. I've tried remapping to a differnt location and getting a specific version + overriting everything. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a permission issue. Not the best error msg i VS....