# TFS Get Latest Downloads No Files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to work on a piece of code in a different Team Project, when I tried to map to a directory on my machine it didn't create a new folder.  And when I try a Get Latest, or even Get Specific Version (with overwrite ticked) it doesn't give me any of the files - the project is still grey in Solution Explorer - and yet it says all files are up to date.

I can't seem to do this for a few projects that I've now tried, I even seem to be struggling to get a Get Latest on the Team Project I am using as it is dropping the bindings so sees everything as not changed.

[There is this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748516/tfs-get-latest-doesnt-copy-files%20this%20question), which says permission issue, but it doesn't give me nearly enough information and may not even be a solution for me.

Comment: Can you share some screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You need **Read** permission for this project. Check the screenshot below and contact your administrator to grant you appropriate permission:

[image]